# Detect / Block Screen sharing by mac app : Swift

Tags: swift, macos, detect, screensharing

I want to check screen sharing is enable by another app like `TeamViewer` or any remote connect app. And disable all the screen sharing and screen recording when my mac app is launch. In iOS `UIScreen.isCaptured` property is provided but for `mac os` apps I can't find such property.

Comment: any luck? looking for the same solution

Comment: @AkashKundu did u figure out any solution ?

Comment: @MohamedِRadwan Unfortunately no. After looking into it, IIRC, multiple websites/apps can share screen at the same time and there's no central API (atleast on Mac) that provides that context. I might be wrong and there might be lower level things you can do, but I didn't look into it that deep.

Comment: There's not an AppKit API to detect screen capture as of now. I will note the Mac Catalyst API `UIScreen.isCaptured` works for folks brining an iOS app to the Mac.